# How to plot two categorical variables using proportion in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two categorical variables v1 is a dichotomous(Yes/No) variable and v2 has multiple outcomes. I wanted to plot the distribution of v2 only in Yes group using ggplot

This is my code, but I am not satisfied with the outcome yet.

```
v1 <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
v2 <- c("Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Green")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1, v2))
df
table(df)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = v1, group = v2)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), stat = "count") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales ::percent_format()) + 
  facet_grid(~v2)
```

I expect the output to only displace proportion Yes among v2.
Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output? Are you expecting to see that there are 3 Yes in Blue, 0 in Green, and 3 in Red, so 50% / 0% / 50% of Yes values across those three groups?

Comment: Exactly. I don't want the percentage of "No" to be displayed in the final output since they complement each other. I also want to add an error bar for the proportion of "Yes" if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use dplyr for creating a dataframe as you want in the following manner:

```
toPlot<-df%>%
    group_by(v1, v2)%>%
    summarise(n = n())%>%
    group_by(v2)%>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```

Then, the graph would be the following:

```
ggplot(data = toPlot, aes(v1, prop, fill = v2)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_grid(~v2)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","green", "red"))
```